# How can I parse string to separate integers? Java

Tags: java, string, io

I need to load (int) data from file. New line separates different data so it's important to know where the new line is. I can use

```
string=readln();
```

and then I have whole line in that string. Then I can

```
string.trim("//s+")
```

which chooses `words(numbers)` from string.

I can parse them to int:

```
int x = parseInt(string.trim("//s+").toString() );
```

Which should work (in theory) but it doesn't! There is Java.lang.something, but no number!
How can I do it?

Comment: There is Java.lang.something? What does that mean?

Comment: Can you show us your whole program? What errors/exceptions are you getting?

Comment: There's no String#trim(String) in java. Please edit your question.

Comment: Don't write Java off the cuff into questions.  It will always be wrong.  Always.  In this case, what is readln()?  String.trim(String)?   Do you mean Integer.parseInt?

Comment: sorry, i can't reproduce that code now :/ Tyler's answer seems reasonable

Comment: I get [Ljava.lang.String;@2aca0115 insted of number

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I like to use a set of two Scanners. One to read in the file line by line, assigning each new line to a temporary String, and another to read the line and gather the ints. Something like this:

```
Scanner sc = new Scanner(inputfile);
Scanner scanLine;
String line;
while(scanLine.hasNextLine())
{
line = sc.nextLine(); 
scanLine = new Scanner(line);
firstInt = scanLine.nextInt();
...
}
```